# .htaccess 301 Redirect for wildcard subdomains

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, subdomain, 301-redirect, multi-subdomains

I run WordPress in Network mode, which means I can have multiple websites running off one installation of WordPress.  Each website runs as a subdomain.  WordPress handles this using .htaccess, and a wildcard subdomain pointing to the location of WordPress, so there are no actual subdomains created in cPanel; just a wildcard subdomain in cPanel, ad WordPress handles the rest.

I want to 301 redirect `http://one.example.com/portfolio` to `http://two.example.com/portfolio`.

If I only have 1 .htaccess file in the web root of example.com, how do I achieve this?

**EDIT**: I have used the following but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^steve\.doig\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/products.html http://tech.doig.com.au/products.html/ [L,R=301]
```

(this is to redirect `http://steve.doig.com.au/products.html` to `http://tech.doig.com.au/products.html`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you should be able to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ http://two.example.com/portfolio [L,R=301]
```

This is from memory, but maybe you get the idea (HTTP_HOST).

Comment: What about redirect, rather than rewrite?

Comment: See my edit to the original question please Leif.

Comment: Okay, I had the time to try it myself. There is slash too much in RewriteRule. Try: RewriteRule ^portfolio$ http://two.example.com/portfolio [L,R=301] (I updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: Good on you!  You've nailed it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Leif, do you know if you can use one line specifying the condition, followed by multiple lines of rewrite rules following the condition?  Do you need to enclose them in parentheses?

Comment: You cannot, but there seem to be some workarounds, like this one: http://my.galagzee.com/2009/02/11/mod_rewrite-one-rewritecond-to-many-rewriterules/ Also try searching for "one rewritecond multiple rewriterule".